# Socket.io-client does not receive any messages after successful connection

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, client-server

I have a working socket.io server up and running, and i am trying to implement a server side socket.io client. Below is the code snippet i have been using for testing. The problem with this is that the client outputs the message only once, in this case it receives 'Welcome' only. I have tried sending messages to the private channel, 'message' via browser but it doesn't show any output even though the server can receive and emit the message successfully.

Client

```
    var io = require('socket.io-client');
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', {'force new connection': true});
    socket.on('connect', function(){
            socket.on('message', function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
            });
    });
```

Server

```
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    var i=0;

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
            socket.emit('message', { 'msg': 'Welcome'});
            socket.on('message', function (from, msg) {
                    socket.emit('message', { 'msg': 'Hello World -  ' + i });
                    i++;
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this?

```
console.log(data.msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing "socket" to "this":

```
this.emit('message', { 'msg': 'Hello World -  ' + i });
```

Answer (score 0):

*You should emit from client side to server. So server can send the data back to client. I guess this code works fine :-)*

**Client**

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', {'force new connection': true});
socket.on('connect', function(){

        socket.on('messageRecieved', function (data) {
                console.log(data);
        });

        socket.emit('message','some message');
});
```

**Server**

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server); 
var i=0;

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('message', function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
                socket.emit('messageRecieved', { 'msg': 'Hello World -  ' + i });
                i++;
        });
});
```